# How to make a sidebar menu with slide-out items?

Tags: css, menu, nav

can you help me out with some guidance on how to make a sidebar menu like on this website: http://www.citroen.fi/, with the menu items sliding out on hover.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list with itens with width 50px for example. On mouse over (:hover selector) you set width to 200px. Add transition property to item to effect (transition: width ease 1s).

Comment: `ul {
  background-color: tomato;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100px;
}

li {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  transition: width ease 1s;
}

li:hover {
  width: 200px;
}

a {
  color: #fff;
}`

Comment: Thanks but all that does is expand the item to the right of the menu.